# Longest Path Neo4j returning incorrect path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph stored in csv format:

```
graphUnioned.csv:
a b
b c
```

The above graph denotes path from Node:a to Node:b. Note that the first column in the file denotes source and the second column denotes destination. With this logic the second path in the graph is from Node:b to Node:c. And the longest path in the graph is: Node:a to Node:b to Node:c.

I loaded the above csv in Neo4j desktop using the following command:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:\\graphUnioned.csv" AS csvLine 
MERGE (s:s {s:csvLine.s}) 
MERGE (o:o {o:csvLine.o}) 
MERGE (s)-[]->(o) 
RETURN *;
```

And then for finding longest path I run the following command:

```
match (n:s)
where (n:s)-[]->() 
match p = (n:s)-[*1..]->(m:o)
return p, length(p) as L
order by L desc
limit 1;
```

However unfortunately this command only gives me path from Node: a to Node:b and does not return the longest path. Can someone please help me understand as to where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your CSV import query.

First, you need to use a type when you MERGE a relationship between nodes, that query won't compile otherwise. You likely supplied one and forgot to add it when you pasted it here.

Second, the big one, is that your query is merging nodes with different labels and different properties, and this is majorly throwing it off. Your intent was to create 3 nodes, with a longest path connecting them, but your query creates 4 nodes, two isolated groups of two nodes each:

This creates 2 b nodes: `(:s {s:b})` and `(:o {o:b})`. Each of them is connected to a different node, and this is due to treating the nodes to be created from each variable in the CSV differently.

What you should be doing is using the same label and property key for all of the nodes involved, and this will allow the match to the b node to only refer to a single node and not create two:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:\\graphUnioned.csv" AS csvLine 
MERGE (s:Node {value:csvLine.s}) 
MERGE (o:Node {value:csvLine.o}) 
MERGE (s)-[:REL]->(o) 
RETURN *;
```

You'll also want an index on :Node(value) (or whatever your equivalent is when you import real data) so that your MERGEs and subsequent MATCHes are fast when performing lookups of the nodes by property.

Now, to get to your longest path query.

If you are assuming that the start node has no relations to it, and that your end node has no relationships from it, then you can use a query like this:

```
match (start:Node)
where not ()-->(start) 
match p = (start)-[*]->(end)
where not (end)-->()
return p, length(p) as L
order by L desc
limit 1;
```